# Timer / Prescaler in microcontrollers

Tags: embedded, microcontroller

Maybe it's a silly question:

I have internal 20 MHz oscillator, 16 bit timer and prescalers (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128) and I want to generate 1 ms delay. I know how to do that - (20 000 000 / 1) / 1000 = 20 000 -> put this value to 16 bit register and it works.

With prescalers 2 and 4, I have the same result 1ms - (20 000 000 / 2) / 1000 = 10 000 and (20 000 000 / 4) / 1000 = 5 000

My question is how to determine which prescaler to use ? Maybe, I have to choose prescaler 4, because this value (5000) is closer to 0 and my timer starts to count from 0 to 5000. If I choose 10 000, the timer will count 2 x 5000.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Why do you think being closer to zero is an advantage?  Conceivably the lower frequency would result in marginally lower power consumption, but I doubt it would be measurable.

Answer (score 6):

You use a higher prescaler when the counter is otherwise not large enough for the period required.  For example if you wanted a 10ms period, you would necessarily need to use a prescaler of *at least* 4 for a reload value of 50000.

The smallest prescaler that results a reload less than 2<sup>16</sup> is what you would normally aim for.  That gives you the highest possible counter resolution which is useful of you are using it for say PWM or input-capture.  If you are just using the reload interrupt on the other hand it is not critical.

If the period you need is not exactly achievable because in is not an exact multiple of the clock period, then using a lower prescaler will minimise the error.

Finally if you go too low, you may not be able to achieve the precise period.  For example for your 1ms period, a prescaler of 64 would result in a reload of 312.5, choosing 312 results in a period of ~1001.603ms or 313 for ~998.403ms.

So generally a reload value as close as possible to 65535 rather than zero as you have suggested is what you you would generally aim for.

Comment: Most Arduino users aren't using external oscillators with any fine precision, but relying on the crappy internal one... so the the microseconds difference you mention is usually academic.  I bet not one in a thousand users posting here knows how to calibrate the oscillator or wire a 10ppm-50ppm precision oscillator.  Makes me laugh when people quibble over microseconds.

Comment: Bear in mind one of the prescalers may affect other peripherals.  In general it should only take a few minutes to write an ad-hoc program that goes through the combinations and searches out the one or ones that are the most accurate (same as you would for the baud rate divisor combinations for some MCUs), you may find and print out multiple combinations that have the same overall accuracy (digitally not counting the analog quality of the clock) and pick from those.  If one of the divisor affects all peripherals you would certainly want to take that into account.

Comment: If with an ideal clock source you need 123456789 counts and one combination can get you 123456700 and another 123456750 you would take the latter so long as it doesnt make some other peripheral worse.

Comment: @TomServo True, but the question is about microcontrollers generally, not Arduino specifically. Apart from that best practice should be applied regardless, so that it becomes a habit for when it is critical. For example I work on applications requiring 2ppm TCXO, with synchronisation to GNSS 1PPS accurate to 60ns. You can laugh, but sometimes it matters.  Moreover it is not simply a matter of "microseconds", it is a matter of drift.  Even at 2ppm a TDMA radio application will fail to meet it's time slot sync requirements after less than a minute without GNSS synchronisation

Comment: According to the datasheet: Internal precision RC oscillator: 20 MHz and ± 4% accuracy when trimmed. Yes, the question is about microcontrollers generally. As I understand, the best is to choose value as close as possible to 65535. I am beginner and just want to know the basic explanation, please do not make it hard.

Comment: @MetodiAngelov Yes.  It is that simple. TomServo is right that it may make little difference, but that is not the point.  One rule/guideline for all. Don't miss the main point though that the primary purpose of the prescaler in this case is to scale to allow the reload to fit the register.

Comment: @Clifford As usual, you are correct.  I commented as though this was a pedestrian Arduino question.  And to other commenters, yes, it's easy to write an Excel or  python calculator to determine optimal/feasible prescalers for All the Atmel parts I use, as well as a more flexible one for the STM32 Nucleos I use on occasion... that answer is posted somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

Mathematally it makes no difference which combination you choose.

The prescaler and the counter are both implemented in hardware and you won't see a performance impact.

However depending on your architecture your prescaler may run permanently and gives you an inaccuracy.

You should send the highest possible frequency (lowest prescaler, most precisest) into your timer/counter as possible.

Comment: The conclusion is right, but I don't follow your reasoning, the higher frequency will not make it any more or less precise so long at the calculated reload value is an integer.

Comment: This is misleading.  First you say it doesn't matter, then you contradict yourself.  If I'm using an external 8192KHz precision oscillator, for example, any number of good prescaler combinations might work, depending on the period I'm trying to achieve.  Bottom line is designers have to think about it.  There is not a necessary relationship between prescaler value and "most precisest" [sic]

Comment: @Clifford: It depends on the use case: Let's say you want to turn on a LED for a fixed duration from your `main()`. You don't know when exactly within the clock interval the LED is turned on. Here you get an inaccuracy of up to one clock period.

Comment: @user5329483 if it were that critical, clearly you 'd use the timer reload interrupt, rather than simply polling a counter. An LED period is not a compelling argument, human visual perception would not the error. The phrase "_prescaler may run permanently_" needs attention, a prescaler is just a click divider, it does not "run".  Either way hour explanation is either wrong or unclear.